# Soundcloud Player "Stratus" Not Appearing

Tags: html, css, soundcloud

I've tried emplenting this new feature that Soundcloud just rolled out, basically a small mini-player at the bottom/top of your website. Instructions are here: http://stratus.sc, which I followed but that player refuses to appear.

**HTML**

```
<head>
<title>About</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.stratus.sc/stratus.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.stratus({
   links: 'http://soundcloud.com/wearelisten/listen_2'
 });
});
</script>  

</head>
```

Yes, instead of using http://stratus.sc/stratus.js that was to be used in the script type part, I just opened the page, copy-pasted into a new .js file, since this won't be actually hosted, this is just a school project. Do I have to make a `div` of some kind to make the player appear? According to their website, the only thing you would have to do is download jQuery (which I've done) & add the scripts to the `<head>` part.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to downgrade your jQuery version.
Unfortunately, that is incompatible with versions of jQuery greater than `1.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the `stratus.js` file i noticed there are some static links to some other files inside

one of which is `/player` page where your js passes the link to play and a settings object, so in other questions you cannot use your player locally.

Comment: Oh.. Even if I use the suggested http://stratus.sc/stratus.js script link instead of copy+pasting into a new .js file, I won't be able to use it locally without hosting?

Comment: Well in that case you should be able to use it as the js from their page makes reference to the local paths of the missing files

Comment: Have you included jQuery js file inside your page ?

Comment: At the top of my HTML? Yes, downloaded the latest and included. (Updating question so full head part can be seen).

Comment: I have tried to install it too but haven't managed to achieve any success, you should try inspiring yourself from the pages it says are using the player

Comment: http://www.deadmau5.com uses it, and my website result should eventually be similar to the whole website but, that's where I've checked. It has divs tho, and I'm wondering if that's what I need.. Soundcloud's trolling me.

Comment: Well on their page states that the function there should be the only thing necessary for that, consider adding some divs then and let me know how it went

Comment: I know, so that's what I did. Well, that's the thing, I'm not sure what to add.. I just started this webdesign course like a month or two ago, so..